# coffeescript check if not in array

Tags: coffeescript

Here's something simple to check if user is in moderator. But I want to check if user is not in moderator.

```
if err && user in moderators
  return
```

Intuitively it would be like this

```
if err && user isnt in moderators
  return
```

But obviously this doesn't work. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`isnt` is the opposite of `is`, which is the triple equals sign. Just negate the `in`:

```
if err and user not in moderators
  return
```

or, using [postfix if](https://coffeescript.org/#conditionals):

```
return if err and user not in moderators
```

Comment: Ohh yeah things make so much more sense now.

Comment: You can also use `if` in postfix form to tidy things up even further:

`return if err and user not in moderators`

Answer (score 13):

In CoffeeScript, NOT can be denoted as ! or not

```
if err && !(user in moderators)

if err && user not in moderators
```

would both work.

Comment: While this may be true, Coffeescript isn't a superset of JavaScript, so not all JavaScript is valid CoffeeScript.

Comment: True. But in this case I think it's fine (should I reword it?)

Comment: I'd remove the JavaScript part. Also, `not` and `!` are equivalent in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Mmk--I don't use coffee script anyway :3